# Convert a pandas df column to dictinary values with a dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'John', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Peter', 'Peter'],
                    'Age': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]})
```

Assume that I have a data frame which is given above. My goal is to convert this data frame to the following dictionary format below. Does anybody know a convenient way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
# Expected Output:
out_df = {'John':[11, 22], 'Sara': [33, 44, 55], 'Peter': [66, 77]}
```

Comment: you can do `df.groupby('Name')['Age'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

First aggregate list and then convert `Series` to dictionary:

```
d = df.groupby('Name')['Age'].agg(list).to_dict()
```